# java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable ERROR when trying to share a print screen through Instagram

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to generate a print screen from my app's current view and share its image through Instagram, but I get the error below...

> W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value >was a [B.  The default value  was returned.
>   Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to
>   android.os.Parcelable
>                                                                                at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:894)
>                                                                                at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7075)
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:9887)

I am using the following functions to share the image:

```
    public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

        final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
        int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

        photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

        return photo;
    }

    private static byte[] getScreenShotByteArray(View view){
        View screenView = view.getRootView();
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
        Bitmap scaledDownBitmap = scaleDownBitmap(bitmap,20,MyApplication.getAppContext());
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        scaledDownBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

The above functions are triggered when the user presses the **insta button**:

```
insta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                // Set the MIME type
                share.setType("image/*");

                //Get view
                View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

                // Add the URI to the Intent.
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getScreenShotByteArray(rootView));
                share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

                // Broadcast the Intent.
                startActivity(share);
            }
        });
```

How can I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM), its value should be:

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

Save your image to a file, not a `byte[]`. Then, configure `FileProvider` to serve that file, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to put in your `Intent`. Be sure to also call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent` before using it with `startActivity()`.

Also:

- Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. It is *your* job to tell the other app with the MIME type is of this content, as *you* are the one choosing that type.
- Please note that only a small percentage of Android users will be Instagram users, and so your app will crash on most devices if you execute this code, as those users will not have Instagram installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but If there is a "Intent putExtra (String name, byte[] value)" function in the API it can be used for sure... I am not using it properly or Instagram might not support it but there is a way.
Also, the app can check if the user has Instagram installed.

Comment: @Siqueira: "it can be used for sure" -- no. You need to follow the documentation, because *the Instagram developers* follow the documentation and expect a `Uri`, not a `byte[]`. That is why you are getting the error that you are. You need to provide Instagram with a `Uri`. "or Instagram might not support it" -- few, if any, `ACTION_SEND` implementations will support a `byte[]`, because most Android developers will follow the documentation and expect to receive a `Uri`.

Comment: The comment about the MIME type is unrealistic. There is (mainly was) a lot of trouble on Android with MIME types. For example, you could share a JSON, which is essentially a plain text file and suddenly all the apps which would handle a plain text file, suddenly can't handle a JSON. This is one of many examples, why using a wildcard or "text/plain" is sometimes necessary, especially on older Android versions.

Comment: @Akito: If you are the *supplier* of content, such as via `EXTRA_STREAM`, you need to provide a concrete MIME type. Otherwise, consumers of content have no idea what it is. If you are the *consumer* of content, such as via an `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_VIEW`, you can advertise support for a range of content types using wildcard types.

Comment: @Akito: "For example, you could share a JSON, which is essentially a plain text file and suddenly all the apps which would handle a plain text file, suddenly can't handle a JSON" -- to an extent, that is a bug in the apps that "handle a plain text file", as they should be advertising support using wildcards. There are ways to work around that limitation, such as by means of multiple `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` objects with different MIME types.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, the gist is, I should limit my app's capabilities, due to other apps not behaving a 100% correct, for the sake of doing it the "right" way? In theory, this might be acceptable from a best practice point of view, but in reality this is just bad. I can't fix all third party apps. It's more realistic to be pragmatic about the issue and use the solution that will certainly work, as long as it does not create further unnecessary trouble. From what I know, using a wildcard does not create any additional mention-worthy trouble.

Comment: @Akito: "for the sake of doing it the "right" way?" -- no, for the sake of reliability. "the solution that will certainly work" -- for the limited scenario of plain text, your approach might work with some apps. However, there are many types of content that do not resemble plain text. For example, if you use `ACTION_SEND` with `image/*` and some arbitrary byte stream, consuming apps will have no idea what format that byte stream represents, because you decided not to tell them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Indeed. I was specifically talking about files which are essentially text files, like JSON, YAML, etc. However, that's a different story.